# Reference an element id from another HTML file

Tags: php, javascript, html, reference

So I have two files one being index.php and the other march.html, I'd like to grab the employee's name out of march.html which I set an id like

```
<h3 id="name">John Doe</h3>
```

So how would I go about grabbing that name out of march.html so I can place it in my index.php. If you want some more detail, it's like employee of the month so I need to grab a name from 11 other files so I can reference them in the index.php. I've tried using DomDocument in php but it's showing a lot of trouble but here is that code just because

```
<?php
      $dom = new DomDocument();
      $dom->validateOnParse = true;
      $dom->loadHtml("march.html");
      $name = $dom->getElementById("name");
      print $name;
?>
```

Comment: "It's showing a lot of trouble"... can you explain what you expect to happen, and what is actually happening? Could it be that `$dom->getElementById("name").Value` or `.innerHtml` would give you what you want?

Comment: @Floris I expect the php to grab "John Doe" and have it print out but it just does nothing.

Comment: $dom->loadHtml parses "march.html" as the document not the content of the file

Comment: @Loris so should I just use Load()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use nodeValue property to get the value:

```
<?php
      $dom = new DOMDocument();
      $dom->validateOnParse = true;
      $dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents("march.html"));
      $name = $dom->getElementById("name")->nodeValue;
      print $name;
?>
```

Comment: returns Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\body.php on line 18. I have march.html in the same folder as index.php

Comment: Slightly more compact:`$dom->loadHTMLFile("march.html");`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a jQuery AJAX call to do that with the specialized ajax function "load"

example:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

jQuery load API:
http://api.jquery.com/load/